# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path [ iOS / Unity3D ]

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

i need your help, so yesterday i want to port my game to iOS, this is not my first time porting it, the previous version always port sucessfully, but not now

i'm using Unity 5.3.4 and 5.3.5 with Xcode 7.3 on El Capitan, its sucessfully compile from the XCode, but all the object that i initilize and spawn at the start of the scene wont show up on the game, i dont know whats wrong with it since theres no error on Unity or XCode itself

but from the logs, i suspect its because of this

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/280DC265-ABD8-41A3-8B87-74D09910FB24/Documentstemp.gjk" is denied.
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in :0
>   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append) [0x00000] in :0
>   at System.IO.File.CreateText (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0

its i assume because, when launch, the game will access texture/sprite from secure website using WWW method, with HTTP not HTTPS, and try to download and save it as sprite at Application.PersistentDataPath and then apply it into the game

its working fine on Android but somehow iOS wont allow to read/write the file, hench the error

heres snippet of the code i use :

```
IEnumerator getBillboard()
{
    WWW getBillboardlistURL = new WWW(billboardlistURL);
    yield return getBillboardlistURL;

    if (getBillboardlistURL.error != null)
    {

    }
    else
    {


        WWW imageLink = new WWW(pictLink[Mathf.FloorToInt(i / 3)]);
        yield return imageLink;
        Texture2D imageTemp = imageLink.texture;
        obj.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite.Create(imageTemp, new Rect(0, 0, imageTemp.width, imageTemp.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
        obj.name = namaProduk[Mathf.FloorToInt(i / 3)];

                print("BILLBOARD ONLINE");

        /// ======= WRITE BILLBOARD NAME TO FILE AND SAVE IT =======



        /// ======================= END ============================


        var bytes = imageLink.texture.EncodeToPNG();

        //print(Application.dataPath);

        //cek file
        if(redownloadImage)
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/vendorBillboard/" + namaProduk[Mathf.FloorToInt(i / 3)] + ".png", bytes);
                    print("REDOWNLOAD SEMUA TEXTURE!");
                }

                obj.SetActive(false);
                billboardPool.Add(obj);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

is there workaround or fix for this?

thank you in advance

Comment: try using `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,texturename)` to make sure you are generating the correct path with correct separators.

Comment: @UriPopov i use the path.combine, while its not giving error on unity itself, but it cant download anything, it cant even check my folder

Comment: np : i test it on PC and androi, both give the same error which cant retrieve texture since its not downloading cause the folder cant even created cause of path.combine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alright...

today i have the chance to test a fix that i come up with, thanks to Needleski.

and yes, it work, for some reason, iOS dont allow me to save a file (in this case any file) to `Application.persistentDataPath` directly,
instead, what i do is, i create a Folder, then create/save the file inside the folder, and it work correctly now

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the exception and comparing it to your code, I don't think the code your provided is where the error is occurring... for 2 reasons:

1. The exception says "UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/280DC265-ABD8-41A3-8B87-74D09910FB24/Documentstemp.gjk" is denied".  However, in your code you have `/vendorBillboard/` in your path.  Notice `/vendorBillboard/` is not in the path in the exception.
2. At the end of the exception it states the problem is in `System.IO.File.CreateText (System.String path)`, however, you have used `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()` in your code.

I'm guessing you are creating a text file "somewhere else" and you are using `Application.dataPath` there instead of `Application.persistentDataPath`.

Comment: thank you for the reply, the code simply just a snippet of whats going on, but generally thats how i retrieve sprite from my website, but yeah, thats also whats confuse me, theres no real indication which one cause the exception,

as for the create text, thanks for pointing out that, i';ll check it again :)

Comment: i just check it again , so @Needleski , i use persistent data path, and this is the only code that i use to create/write text file : http://pastebin.com/EDTXUrVd , is there any other reason that you can see cause the exception, i honestly confuse :/

Comment: aaaahhhh, i think i see the problem,i write the file directly to persistentdatapath, i'll try to change it and save it into a folder by creat the folder first, its work on the sprite, it should be work with the text file , will update soon-ish

Comment: System.IO.File.CreateText(Application.persistentDataPath + "temp.gjk");

Should be:

System.IO.File.CreateText(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "temp.gjk"));